# Dynamically create instance of Repository pattern

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, reflection, system.reflection

I am using a repository pattern in 4.8 with DI and EF 6

This is my Repo

```
public class LookupRepositoryBase<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : AbstractBase, new()
       {
              public readonly SampleModel _context; 
              public LookupRepositoryBase(SampleModel injectedContext) : base(injectedContext)
              {
                     _context = injectedContext;
               
              }
}
```

AS you can see it accepts any class that uses the AbstractBase
normally DI handles the constructor of the SampleModel which is the EF Data Context

in my test console all I can simply do something like

```
LookupRepositoryBase<Bob> bobRepo = new LookupRepositoryBase<Bob>('insert ef data context here');
```

I am trying to do this dynamically since I have about 30 classes (all for drop downs) I need to load dynamically

here is what I have thus far

```
                     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("Web.Data.dll");

                     Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fi.FullName);
                     Type genericClass = assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "LuBob");
                     Type typeArgument2 = assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "SampleModel");

                
                     Type genericClassRepo = typeof(LookupRepositoryBase<>);
           

                     //genericClass.

                     Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType();
              
                     object created = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);

my problem is how do I insert/ make the constructor for my LookupRepositoryBase
```

I do not want to have to make a seperate method in the repo for setting it

Comment: Are you asking how to call the constructor you have already created? `Activator.CreateInstance` does that, you just need to specify the parameters so it calls the right now, for example: `Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass, nameOfContext);`

Comment: sorry first time using this approach, so my class needs 2 things the Generic object in the constructor <LuBoB> and the constructor for the dbContext, just confused how to make this all work

Comment: I am getting this error  System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot create an instance of _ngADAMWeb.Data.Repos.Concrete.LookupRepositoryBase`1[TEntity] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.'